# is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handlind

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I get those message when building for IOS, it succeed but IOS notification don't work, i get the messaging/registration-token-not-registered by FCM, so I thought this post may have been related to this error.

[image]

It's saying that my registration token is not registered. After looking into the firebase doc i saw that : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#admin_sdk_error_reference

messaging/registration-token-not-registered :

The provided registration token is not registered. A previously valid registration token can be unregistered for a variety of reasons, including:

The client app unregistered itself from FCM
The client app was automatically unregistered.(This can happen if the user uninstalls the application or, on iOS, if the APNS Feedback Service reported the APNS token as invalid.)
The registration token expired. (For example, Google might decide to refresh registration tokens or the APNS token may have expired for iOS devices.)
The client app was updated, but the new version is not configured to receive messages.
For all these cases, remove this registration token and stop using it to send messages.

But i feel like i already filled all the requirement (APNS is already configured and added into Firebase console)

```
⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                          ^


⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:24: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                                      ^



⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                                      ^


⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

  [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                               ^


⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:306:1: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging
                                                           ^


⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

  [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
^


⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:195:43: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

- (void)applicationReceivedRemoteMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                                           ^

⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:307:24: 'FIRMessagingRemoteMessage' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs for downstream message handling. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    didReceiveMessage:(FIRMessagingRemoteMessage *)remoteMessage {
                                                      ^

⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:141:30: 'shouldEstablishDirectChannel' is deprecated: FCM direct channel is deprecated, please use APNs channel for downstream message delivery. [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

    [FIRMessaging messaging].shouldEstablishDirectChannel = true;
                                                      ^

⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:196:52: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

  [self didReceiveRemoteNotification:remoteMessage.appData];
                                                               ^

⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:306:1: implementing deprecated method [-Wdeprecated-implementations]

- (void)messaging:(FIRMessaging *)messaging

⚠️  /Users/builder/programs/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase_messaging-6.0.16/ios/Classes/FLTFirebaseMessagingPlugin.m:308:63: 'appData' is deprecated [-Wdeprecated-declarations]

  [_channel invokeMethod:@"onMessage" arguments:remoteMessage.appData];
^


⚠️  /Users/builder/clone/ios/Runner/AppDelegate.swift:11:58: conditional cast from 'AppDelegate' to 'UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate' always succeeds

      UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
^  ~~~~
```

Comment: Direct channel is deprecated but still works in Firebase 6. It is unrelated to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The device token can change over time, so if you store the device token you need to make sure you [refresh the token](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/messaging/server-integration/#saving-tokens) each time the app is started.